# Tikz shading Issues

Tags: pgfplots, shading

In the code below if I use the following code `soft clip={domain=-3:3}`, I get the graph on the top. If I use `soft clip={domain=-2.99:3}`, I get the graph on the bottom. Why does -3 not work?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,decorations,intersections,matrix,calc,backgrounds,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=center, axis y line=center,
    ticks=none,
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={below right}, ylabel style={above left},
    xmin=-3.25, xmax=3.25, ymin=-1.25, ymax=1.25,
    x=1.5cm/1, y=2cm/1,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=200, smooth,name path=C] {(x^2-1)/(x^2+1)};
    \addplot[name path=HA, domain=-3:3, dashed] {1};
    \draw (axis cs:1, 0.9) node[above] {\small$y=1$};
    \draw (axis cs:0.5, 0.25) node {\textbf{\small$R_1$}};
    \addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=C and HA, soft clip={domain=-2.99:3}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you remove scale option or decrease it to 0.8, then your MWE works also width `soft clip={domain=-3:3}`

Comment: Any news? Should we close your question as "unclear what you're asking"?

Answer (score 1):

Let me extend my comment to answer- You have two possibilities:

- reduce scale: `scale=0.8`
- remove scale and for determining image width use option `width=<length>`

And of course combination of both aforementioned possibilities. In all cases the result is very similar (difference is in image size, which can be simple determined in the second case):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} % <-- added

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,calc,decorations,intersections,matrix,patterns,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
    width=7cm,  % <-- here determine image size
    axis x line=center, axis y line=center,
    ticks=none,
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={below right}, ylabel style={above left},
    xmin=-3.25, xmax=3.25, ymin=-1.25, ymax=1.25,
    x=1.5cm/1, y=2cm/1,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-3:3, samples=200, smooth,name path=C] {(x^2-1)/(x^2+1)};
    \addplot[name path=HA, domain=-3:3, dashed] {1};
    \draw (axis cs:1, 0.9) node[above] {\small$y=1$};
    \draw (axis cs:0.5, 0.25) node {\textbf{\small$R_1$}};
    \addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]
        fill between[of=C and HA, soft clip={domain=-3:3}]; %<-- see soft clip
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```